# Linear Algebra Vector, plane question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a room with a wall (partition) partially blocking your view. Suppose your eye is at point $[0, 0, 0]$, and the wall has one corner at $[−10, −5, 20]$, where the coordinates are in the order [left→right, down→up, you→away-in-front]. The wall consists of all the points $[−10, −5, 20] + \alpha_1[30; 0; 20] + \alpha_2[0, 20, 0]$, for $0 ≤ \alpha ≤ 1$. You cannot see any object behind the wall.

(a) Can you see an object at position $[0,0,100]$?

(b) For what $\gamma > 0$ can you see an object straight in front of you at position $[0; 0; \gamma]$?

Hint: ﬁnd the intersection between the plane of the wall and the ray from your eye to the object: point of intersection = $[−10, −5, 20] + \alpha_1[30, 0, 20] + \alpha_2[0, 20, 0] = \beta [object]$ for some $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta$.

I have been working on this problem for a few hours and can't seem to be able to formulate a proper answer to either question. I set up an equation in the form $A * [1, \alpha_1, \alpha_2] = [0, 0, \gamma]$ but I got stuck after solving for a few possibilities of  am $\alpha_n$ that meets the criteria $\alpha > 0$ but $\leq 1$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can change the numbers to whatever you want and help me with the answer, its not the numbers I am concerned about its the method I would like help with.

Comment: You can find $\gamma$ by solving the equation $(0,0,\gamma)=(-10,-5,20)+\alpha_1(30,0,20)+\alpha_2(0,20,0)$, which is equivalent to three equations: $\gamma=20+20\alpha_1$, $-10+30\alpha_1=0$, and $-5+20\alpha_2=0$. Just remember to make sure the solution for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ is in the allowed range.

Comment: How did you get the equations you gave? I understand where you got all the numbers, just why do the first two equations have α1 and the third equation have α2?

Comment: Firstly, to multiply a vector by a number, you multiply each coordinate by that number, for instance, $\alpha_1(30,0,20)=(30\alpha_1,0,20\alpha_1)$. Secondly, to add two vectors, you add their coordinates, $(-10,-5,20)+(30\alpha_1,0,20\alpha_1)=(-10+30\alpha_1,-5,20+20\alpha_1)$. You can then add the third vector following the same idea. Finally, when two vectors are equal, it means all their coordinates are equal. So you get three equations, one for each coordinate.

Comment: That's all true. But you're trying to find a plane in three dimensions (the wall) given with only two variables ($\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$). I'm also quite lost.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Sokolov, that makes sense. I finally ended up getting it figured out. γ ended up coming out to 80/3 and the α's still met the requirements.

Comment: @scott_fakename A plane is 2 dimensional, so it only needs two coordinates to describe it.